# Como deixar o IFRAME editável?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Me lembro a muito tempo de ter usado um código em um `IFRAME` que permitia que eu digitasse, colocasse negrito ou itálico nas fontes, dentro desse `iframe`.

Eu sei que não é com a opção `contenteditable`, era outra forma de configuração.

Fiz essa pergunta mesmo só pra relembrar:

Qual é o atributo que, ao ser alterado, permite que eu possa deixar um `iframe` editável?

*Nota*: Eu tenho quase certeza que eu fazia isso pelo Javascript, mas não estou mais lembrado.

Comment: Ja deu uma olhada nesse link abaixo? Acho que pode ajudar você, mas é feito em jquery
https://codepen.io/andreich1980/pen/RWBzjX

Comment: mesmo dominio ou de dominio diferente?

Comment: No mesmo domínio

Comment: A ideia que tenho é passar parametros no src do iframe, recuperar esses parametros na pagina iframe e aplicar no css

Comment: Agora fiquei confuso, mas seria algo desse tipo? só fiz para alguns parametros nos estilos das letras do iframe mas pode passar quantos parametros desejar  http://kithomepage.com/sos/pagina-com-iframe.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use o `designMode=on`, mas isto deve ser definido dentro do documento que estiver dentro do iframe, setar diretamente no elemento `<iframe>` não vai dar certo, então por exemplo crie um iframe assim:

```
var editor = document.querySelector("iframe#editor");

if (editor) {
    var d = editor.contentDocument;
    d.document.designMode = "on";
}
```

O HTML sendo assim:

```
<iframe src="editor.html"></iframe>
```

Note que o `src=""` deve ser do mesmo domínio, caso contrário não terá como obter o `contentDocument`

> **Nota:** até aonde me recordo `designMode` opera via JavaScript (ou APIs externas da interface usada em `webView`s, por exemplo um aplicativo próprio), não tem como setar diretamente **no HTML**, o único caminho é usar `<[Element] contenteditable="true">`, pode pode exemplo definir diretamente no `<body>`, por exemplo:

---

### Criar um editor com iframe dinâmico (sem a existência de uma página extra)

Os navegadores modernos possuem a propriedade `srcdoc="<conteudo HTML>"`, você então pode setar dinamicamente o conteúdo, o que pode ser bem útil e muito mais pratico, acaso queira criar um editor de texto:

JavaScript:

```
var editor = document.querySelector("iframe#editor");

if (editor) {
    editor.contentDocument.designMode = "on";
}
```

HTML:

```
<iframe id="editor" srcdoc="<p>Foo, Bar</p>"></iframe>
```

> **Nota:** Sandbox não permite interação direta, portanto irá falhar

---

### Propriedade `Element.contentEditable`

A diferença básica do `designMode` para `contentEditable` o é que o primeiro altera o documento, já o segundo é capaz de editar apenas um elemento, exemplo do `contentEditable`

> **Nota:** true e false em `contentEditable` devem ser strings e não booleanos, ao menos no momento de checar/leitura da propriedade.

```html
Stack Overflow<br>

<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
  Olá, mundo!
</div>

Stack Overflow<br>
```

Com Javascript:

```js
var ativar = document.querySelector("#ativar");

if (ativar) {
    ativar.onclick = function () {
        var editor = document.querySelector("div#editor");

        if (editor) {
            if (editor.contentEditable === "true") {
                 editor.contentEditable = "false"; //Desativa
            } else {
                 editor.contentEditable = "true"; //Ativa
                 editor.focus();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

```html
Stack Overflow<br>

<div id="editor">
  Olá, mundo!
</div>

Stack Overflow<br>

<button id="ativar">Ativar/desativa editor</button>
```

---

### execCommand: Negrito, itálico e sublinhado e mais

Tanto o contentEditable quanto o designMode suportam o comando [**`execCommand`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand), o campo que estiver com "foco" receberá o comando do `document.execCommand`, comandos suportados:

`backColor`, `bold`, `contentReadOnly`, `copy`, `createLink`, `cut`, `decreaseFontSize`, `delete`, `enableInlineTableEditing`, `enableObjectResizing`, `fontName`, `fontSize`, `foreColor`, `formatBlock`, `forwardDelete`, `heading`, `hiliteColor`, `increaseFontSize`, `indent`, `insertBrOnReturn`, `insertHorizontalRule`, `insertHTML`, `insertImage`, `insertOrderedList`, `insertUnorderedList`, `insertParagraph`, `insertText`, `italic`, `justifyCenter`, `justifyFull`, `justifyLeft`, `justifyRight`, `outdent`, `paste`, `redo`, `removeFormat`, `selectAll`, `strikeThrough`, `subscript`, `superscript`, `underline`, `undo`, `unlink` e `styleWithCSS`

> **Nota:** O `useCSS` esta em desuso
>
> **Nota:** irei editar em breve e detalhar os comandos

Exemplo de uso:

```js
document.querySelector("#negrito").onclick = function() {
    document.execCommand("bold");
};

document.querySelector("#italico").onclick = function() {
    document.execCommand("italic");
};

document.querySelector("#sublinhado").onclick = function() {
    document.execCommand("strikeThrough");
};
```

```css
.editor {
    border: 1px #c0c0c0 solid;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    min-width: 400px;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<button id="negrito">Negrito</button>
<button id="italico">Italico</button>
<button id="sublinhado">Sublinhado</button>

<hr>

Stack Overflow<br>

<div class="editor" contenteditable="true">
  Olá, mundo 1!
</div>

<div class="editor" contenteditable="true">
  Olá, mundo 2!
</div>

<div class="editor" contenteditable="true">
  Olá, mundo c-137!
</div>

Stack Overflow<br>
```

Comment: e como colocar negrito ou itálico nas fontes?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo adicionei um exemplo na resposta, veja se fica fácil de entender, note que o document.execCommad serve para qualquer elemento com contentEditable, desde que esteja com o foco e que o `document` seja o mesmo (creio eu).

Comment: Show!! vc é o cara!

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de fazer isso com `iframe` sem página é aplicando `contentEditable` direto no `body` do `iframe` com JavaScript:

**HTML:**

```
<iframe src="" style="width: 50%; height: 150px;" id="iframe"></iframe>
```

**JS:**

```
window.onload = function(){
   var frameElement = document.getElementById("iframe");
   var doc = frameElement.contentDocument;
   doc.body.contentEditable = true;
}
```

[**Veja no JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wfgvoz97/1/) devido à limitações do snippet local.

### EDIT

Você pode também alterar estilos acessando o CSS:

```
doc.body.style.fontSize = '30px';
doc.body.style.color = 'red';
```

Comment: e como colocar negrito ou itálico nas fontes?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Negrito CTRL+b e itálico CTRL+i

Comment: Melhorou, e mudar as cores, font, tamanho etc...?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo adicionei na resposta. :)